# Syntax error of conditional in JQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I want to do some kind of data-driven GUI using conditional in Jquery template, but for the following code part:

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
          <li>  
                 {{if checkFile(${link})}}  
                     <p class="buttons"> <a href = ${link}>${type}</a></p>  
                 {{else}}  ${type}
                 {{\if}} 
           </li> 
 </script>
```

I got the error from the browser javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Am I missing something in using conditional in Jquery template??
I couldn't see anything wrong according to

Comment: try: change `\if` to `/if`

Comment: @AnhTú Oops.. Oh, also, the `checkFile(${link})` should be `checkFile(link)`..